# sitecore publishing initializing 7.1

Tags: sitecore, publish

My website worked right.

Yesterday I setup Windows Server 2008 SP1 patch， and some safe files:
KB3011780,KB4012212,KB976902

and then, publish item does not work!

This is the error image:
[image: this is the error img]

And below are the logs:

```
Heartbeat 12:47:58 ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.Publishing.StartPublishingRemoteEvent
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName)
   at Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesProvider.IsUserInRole(User user, Role targetRole, Boolean includeIndirectMemberships)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule.RuleApplies(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType, AccessPermission permission, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable entity, AccessRight right, Account account)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions.GetPublishingTargets()
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions..ctor(Database sourceDatabase, Database targetDatabase, PublishMode mode, Language language, DateTime publishDate)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.DistributedPublishingManager.DecodeOptions(DistributedPublishOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.DistributedPublishingManager.GetOptions(DistributedPublishOptions[] options)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.DistributedPublishingManager.StartPublishing(StartPublishingRemoteEvent event)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.RemoteEventMap.OnGenericRemoteEvent[TEvent](TEvent event)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What u want to ask?

Comment: Related: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/549

Comment: One quick solution is just recycle app pool. It should work.

Comment: Things to check: Does it work as a full admin? Does it work after an app pool reset (as @S.K mentions) If you point a clean installation at the same database, does the publishing work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **“Trace Failed Requests”** feature enabled, it may cause such errors when HttpContext is not available. Try disabling it or, at least, decreasing tracing level down to “Warning”

```
<add provider="ASPNET" ... verbosity="Warning" />
```

Find more info about Trace Failed Requests [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it worked normally ,sometimes do not work.
i copy the website files to another server,it work!
somebody know why? thank you very much!

Comment: another server use the same database , same windows server 2008 R2 SP1.